# codeIgniter Datamapper Performance on Joins with include_related

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-datamapper

I'm using codeIgniter 2.1.4 with Datamapper and i worry about Datamapper performance.

My results are only **2 rows** and return successfully!

But when i dumped `$posts` with `var_dump($posts)`, I'm getting **20.000 code lines** with included all data/relations/configs/tables/fields/languages etc..

Sorry, I couldnt paste dumped data because of excessive lines.

What's the problem? Where am I doing wrong?

Its my sample query:

```
$posts = new post_model();
$posts->where('active', 1)
      ->where('slug', $slug)
      ->include_related('users', '*', 'user', true)
      ->include_related('categories', '*', 'category', true)
      ->include_related('tags', '*', 'tag', true)
      ->include_related('groups', '*', 'group', true)
      ->get_paged($this->uri->segment(4), 50, TRUE);
```

Include Related Model Assignments:

```
public $has_one = array('users' => 
                                array(
                                  'class' => 'users_m',
                                  'other_field' => 'post',
                                  'model_path' => 'application/modules/users',
                                ),
                         'categories' => array(),
                         'tags'       => array(),
                         'groups'     => array(),
                  );
```

Posts Related Assignments:

```
public $has_one = array(
    'request' => array(
        'class' => 'posts_m',
        'model_path' => 'application/modules/posts',
    )
);
```

### By the way..

I set `instantiate` as `false` and dumped data decreased to **3.000** lines.. I really didnt understand..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't doing anything wrong -- this is just the way it is.

> Try to understand how PHP, and CodeIgniter work.
>
> In PHP5, all objects are assigned by reference. This means that
>   although you see them when you access a Datamapper object, they are
>   not copies, and don’t take up memory.
>
> CodeIgniter works by assigning all objects as singletons to $this, so
>   a var_dump($this) will show you pages and pages of object information.
>   All other objects that access CI ( either via an automatic mechanism
>   or through get_instance() ) use references.
>
> So obviously you’ll see all this when you dump a Datamapper object.
>   Because Datamapper accesses the database, language, and form
>   validation libraries, which in turn have links to several other
>   libraries.

http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/188420/#890508

---

> `$instantiate` - If `TRUE`, then actual objects are instantiated and populated with the columns automatically.

http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/getadvanced.html

Instantiate `TRUE` means more data. Intantiate `FALSE` means less data.

Comment: When i dumped `$posts` variable, in fact did i dumped codeigniter `$this` object because of referenced? Did I understand correctly?

Comment: And when i tried to save the results as cache, cached file is huge size. How can i get only current query results without referenced codeigniter data?

Comment: `var_dump` (and related) will give you all of the extraneous data. Don't use `var_dump`. Otherwise you will be getting a DataMapper ORM object.